# Equivalent plain vanilla JavaScript code needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the equivalent plain vanilla JavaScript code for the following jQuery snippet, please let me know if anyone can assist.

```
 var checkedOption = jQuery('input[name=f:t:checkBoxSw]:checked').val();
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service. I'm also pretty sure that selector is invalid in the first place.

Comment: Your code seems to be invalid you need to double-quote name value `[name="f:t:checkBoxSw"]`

Comment: @Anton: The quotes are not required if there are no spaces in that part of the selector.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, custom selectors cannot occur in `[name=x]` segments. I double-checked and that selector does throw an invalid expression error.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=f:t:checkBoxSw]`

Comment: Well, see [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), it might help. Good luck.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Well done (just odd naming then). Comment retracted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var f_t_checkBoxSws = document.getElementsByName('f:t:checkBoxSw');
var f_t_checkBoxSw, f_t_checkBoxSw_val;

for (i=0; i<f_t_checkBoxSws.length; i++) {
  f_t_checkBoxSw = f_t_checkBoxSws[i];

  if (f_t_checkBoxSw.tagName == 'input' && f_t_checkBoxSw.checked) {
    f_t_checkBoxSw_val = f_t_checkBoxSw.value;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: We should merge answers :) Wouldn't `getElementsByName` be better rather than looping all inputs? Or is there a reason you did it this way I'm not seeing?

Comment: I believe jquery will do that behavior if `document.querySelector` is not available.

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/sizzle-jquery-selector-pitfalls), *jQuery will actually watch for the case $('[name='+name+']) and use the native document.getElementsByName function*

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks. Although I'm pretty sure that didn't always use to be the case.